# How to test an abstract data type?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing, types

Suppose we have a module that defines an abstract type T:

```
module AbstractType (T, lexer) where

data T = T String deriving Show

lexer = (fmap T) . words
```

(Note that we do not export any type constructors for T, so the user would not be able to draft an instance by hand.)

How does one unit test `lexer` function?

Sure we may use the Show property of T, like this:

```
module Main where

import AbstractType

main = test
    (show $ lexer "summer is miles and miles away")
        "[T \"summer\",T \"is\",T \"miles\",T \"and\",T \"miles\",T \"away\"]"

test :: (Eq a) => a -> a -> IO ()
test expression expectation
    | expression == expectation = putStrLn "Test passed."
    | otherwise = error "Test failed."
```

— But this is both not beautiful and unfit for cases when our abstract type is not an instance of a class that permits casting to another, constructable type.

Is there a remedy?

P.S. To provide some justification for the case: suppose we have a chain of functions like `parser . lexer` that we can integration test and see if the whole of it works. As the chain at hand gets more complex, it may nevertheless become desirable to unit test each link individually.

The example is a simplified excerpt from an actual toy text processor I am in the process of writing.

Comment: If `T` is so abstract that you cannot access its constructors *and* you provide no functions that operate on values of type `T`, how would you use it for anything useful in the first place? In the example you have provided, you cannot do anything with a `T` except `show` it, which makes the example a bit too contrived to give an answer for.

Comment: As an addition to the previous comment, it is customary not to hide things permanently but instead export the things which normal users are not intended to see in the form of `Internal` modules. There is an unwritten (I think) agreement that anything goes inside an `Internal` module, so as a library author you are free to change anything you want without backward compatibility concerns and if anyone imports the module in their code they are on their own. This is better than deciding for *everyone* that they cannot import things even if they know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The [generally accepted](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8w90ia/test_non_public_functions/) best practice is, for an exposed module `A`, to create an internal module `A.Internal` that is either:

1. Exposed but documented to be unstable or unsafe.
2. Not exposed to the users of the package, but only to the testing facilities. *(This is made possible by the [internal libraries](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/269) feature released in Cabal 2.0.)*

It is my understanding that functions that are not exposed enjoy more radical optimizations, particularly inlining. I am not sure if it applies to functions in internal libraries too.

On the other hand, situations often arise when a user desperately needs some internal feature of your library and ends up forking and patching it to gain access. This is, of course, unfortunate and undesirable.

I would say generally that the implementation of an abstract type is best kept in an internal library as a safety measure, but you should use your judgement in each particular case.